# this custom array adapter is not working on integers

Tags: java, android

i have written a custom array adapter for practice so .. this below code is working when i am using  strings as variable in data.java class but if i use integers variables instead it will get installed in the AVD but will not open...

**main activity.java**

enter code here

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ArrayList<data> arr= new ArrayList<>();
    arr.add(new data("2","6","india","4","22222"));
    ListView listView=findViewById(R.id.list);
    adpater a=new adpater(this,arr);
    listView.setAdapter(a);
 }
}
```

**adapter.java**

```
public class adpater  extends ArrayAdapter<data> {
public adpater(Activity context, List<data> arrayList) {
    super(context,0, arrayList);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list,parent,false);
    }
    data currentitem = getItem(position);
    TextView textView=convertView.findViewById(R.id.location);
    TextView textView1=convertView.findViewById(R.id.recovered);
    TextView textView2=convertView.findViewById(R.id.dead);
    TextView textView3=convertView.findViewById(R.id.confirmed);
    TextView textView4=convertView.findViewById(R.id.updated);
    textView.setText(currentitem.getCountry());
    textView1.setText(currentitem.getRecovered());
    textView2.setText(currentitem.getDead());
    textView3.setText(currentitem.getConfirmed());
    textView4.setText(currentitem.getUpdated());
    return  convertView;
 }
}
```

**data.java**

```
public class data {
private  String  confirmed;
 private String dead;
private String country;
private String recovered;
private String updated;





public String  getConfirmed() {
    return confirmed;
}

public String getDead() {
    return dead;
}

public String getRecovered() {
    return recovered;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public String getUpdated() {
    return updated;
}
public data(String Confirmed,String Dead,String Country,String Recovered,String Updated){
    confirmed=Confirmed;
    dead=Dead;
    country=Country;
    recovered=Recovered;
    updated=Updated;
 }
}
```

my problem is that if i will use any of the integer variables here ..it will not work.
i dont know if its good question but this really messed me up...

Comment: Because setText method on TextView with int argument is looking for resource with int id not actually set int as a text, use String.valueOf to parse data int field to string then set as text to textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause**

When you use a `String` variable, the `TextView` will use [setText(CharSequence)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence)) method and it works well. But when you use an `int` variable, the `TextView` will use [setText(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)) method, the param is a special int type, it refers to the int resource type in R class that created by the compiler in build time, it won't understand if you pass a normal int to it.

**Solution**

Cast the `int` to `String` type, so the `TextView` will use `setText(CharSequence)` method instead.

Assume in data class, the `confirmed` variable is an `int` type, then change your code from

```
textView3.setText(currentitem.getConfirmed());
```

to

```
textView3.setText(currentitem.getConfirmed() + "");
```

or

```
textView3.setText(String.valueOf(currentitem.getConfirmed()));
```

Comment: thanks mate i had always heard that community helps ... today i saw it ... thanks brooo!!!!!!!!

Comment: @rahimvirani Glad to help you. By the way, if this answer solved your problem, please accept it as the answer. Happy coding :D